# How to delete a specific value from a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

I was given a task with a DOUBLY linked list to delete a specific number from the list. My code is giving an Access Violation error. Even after multiple dry runs, I can't figure out what is wrong. The task basically is to create a search function which finds a specific number in the linked list, and a deletion function which deletes that specific link.

```
node* search(int val){
    node* cur=head;
    while(cur!=NULL){
        if(cur->data==val){
            cout<<"value found "<<val<<endl;
            return cur;
        }
        cur=cur->next;
    }
    cout<<"value not exist"<<endl;
    return NULL;
}

bool delspval(int val){
    node*temp=0;
    if(search(val)==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        temp=search(val);
        temp->prev->next=temp->next;
        delete temp;
        temp=0;
        cout<<"specific value "<<val<<" deleted"<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

In the above given code, the line `temp->prev->next=temp->next;` is giving the error. I'm pretty much a beginner at linked lists, so any help would be appreciated.

minimal working code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class dll{
    struct node{
        int data;
        node *next,*prev;
    };
    node *head;
public:
    dll(){
        head=NULL;
    }
    void inatst(int val){
        node *temp=new node;
        temp->data=val;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
    node* search(int val){
        node* cur=head;
        while(cur!=NULL){
            if(cur->data==val){
                cout<<"value found "<<val<<endl;
                return cur;
            }
            cur=cur->next;
        }
        cout<<"value not exist"<<endl;
                    return NULL;
    }
    bool delspval(int val){
        node*temp=0;
        if(search(val)==NULL){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            temp=search(val);
            temp->prev->next=temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp=0;
            cout<<"specific value "<<val<<" deleted"<<endl;
            return 1;
                }
            }
    void display(){
        node*cur=head;
        while(cur!=NULL){
            cout<<cur->data<<" ";
            cur=cur->next;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    ~dll(){
        while(head!=NULL){
            node*cur=head;
            head=cur->next;
            delete cur;
            cur=head;
        }
    }
};
void main(){
    dll l1;
    l1.inatst(1);
    l1.inatst(2);
    l1.inatst(3);
    l1.inatst(4);
    l1.inatst(5);
    l1.inatst(6);
    l1.display();
    l1.delspval(3);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it compiles and does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don’t use all caps in heading, it amounts to shouting.

Comment: In `temp->next->prev` you don't check if `next` is `NULL`. That would give you an access error. Aside: there is an inefficiency from calling `search(val)` twice.

Comment: Make the list circular or use a dummy element to avoid that error-prone and inefficient `nullptr` special case. Next, a **doubly** linked list must have **two** links updated. First: `temp->next->prev = temp->prev;` (Never assign a `next` into a `prev` like you did!) Second: `temp->prev->next = temp->next;` Also, *always* run it under `valgrind`; it will tell you when exactly you start using invalid pointers.

Comment: Unrelated: One of the best tools when debugging a linked list is the pencil and paper. Draw the list. redraw the list at every step of a transformation, making absolutely certain that you do not lose a connection before you no longer need it. Then use the pictures as the basis for your code or as a the set of expectations while debugging. If you step through the code with a debugger, redrawing according to what the debugger does as you step, can you draw the exact same pictures? If not, where the pictures diverge is probably your bug.

Comment: Just because I haven't seen it mentioned, you should not call `search(val)` twice inside `delspval`. Searching for a value in a linked list is *extremely slow*. Instead of `node*temp=0`, you should write `node*temp=search(val)`, and then then check if `temp === NULL` on the next line.

Comment: @weathervane that is absolutely correct but i was making all the functions including delete at start and end as well so while making specific value deletion i didnt consider using any ending values from the list so neither the previous is empty nor the next but thanks for the advice

Comment: @hadikhan now, with the proper mcve shown. Look at your `inatst` function and ask yourself what happens with the `prev` pointer of the old node sitting at `head` (if there was one) when you prepend the new node to the list and it become the head? The answer is *nothing*. it is *never* configured in any of  that code, yet relied on as pristine in your delete operation. In fact, the prev member doesn't look like it is every touched by *anything*, *anywhere*, except your delete operation. that's not going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, the `search()` function is being called twice within the `delspval()` function:

```
if(search(val)==NULL){
```

and

```
temp=search(val);
```

that makes the `delspval()` function less efficient.

This statement:

```
temp->next->prev=temp->next;
```

does not make sense.

The `delspval()` function can be defined in the following way. I suppose that the class contains only one pointer to the `head` node. If the class contains also a pointer to the `tail` node, then the function below must be modified.

```
bool delspval( int val )
{
    node *temp = search( val );
    bool success = temp != nullptr;

    if ( success )
    {
        if ( temp->next != nullptr )
        {
            temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
        }
        // If the class has a pointer to the tail node
        //   then uncomment the else part  
        /*
        else
        {
            tail = temp->prev;
        }
        */

        if ( temp->prev != nullptr )
        {
            temp->prev->next = temp->next;
        }
        else
        {
            head = temp->next;
        }

        delete temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: there was a mistake in the above given code *temp->next->prev=temp->next;* was supposed to be  *temp->prev->next=temp->next;* i was trying different things and forgot to change but still it is giving access violation error .... and the inefficiency for using the function twice is noted thanks <3

Comment: @hadikhan Do you have a pointer to the tail node in the class?

Comment: no i have int data , node*next,*prev in node struct and node *head in link class

Comment: @hadikhan If so then you have a mistake in some other functions.

Comment: but if i exclude this funtion in the main body the program works perfectly fine

Comment: @hadikhan we're having to take it on tremendous (and ultimately naive) faith that the *rest* of your code is far better than *this* function, so as to produce a valid double-linked list on which to execute the above function. This is the reason it is so vital a proper [mcve] be included [**in your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73748757/edit).

Comment: @hadikhan It can be a result of incorrect settings of pointers prev and next of each node including the head node

Comment: @Whozcraig i will edit it in my post

Comment: @hadikhan You should close the question selecting the best answer and ask a new question where you will provide a minimal complete program with the function I showed.

Comment: @vladfrommoscow will do

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely not call search twice. You basically double the runtime.

But the solution if the value was found: If tmp->next is not null then it points to tmp, but it now needs to the item before tmp. And if tmp->prev is not then it points to tmp, but it needs to point to the item after tmp.

And finally, if tmp = head then head must be changed to the item after tmp.

```
Tmp = search()
If tmp == null then return
Prev = tmp->prev
Next = tmp->next
If prev ≠null then prev->next = next
If next ≠ null then next->prev = prev
If head = tmp then head = next. 
Delete tmp.
```